# Why do I get 502 errors in a load balancer, but not 5XXs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

My Load balancer shows 502 errors, but not 5XXs errors.

[image]

Comment: Maybe 5XX is meant for the other 500-level errors not covered by a specific panel.

Comment: http shows both, but you cannot see it here in the screenshot

Comment: What does "http shows both, but you cannot see it here" mean?

Comment: Can you open the metric in CloudWatch and get the exact names of the metrics? Screenshot is only showing the graph title, metric could be anything.

Comment: Is this is a custom dashboard?

Comment: @DejanPeretin I changed the screenshot, can you look at it, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, this is an application load balancer (and not a classic or network load balancer).

Here are the docs for ALB metrics: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html

Graph titled **HTTP 5XXs** is showing the `HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count` metric. Which is the number of HTTP response codes generated **by the targets**. This does not include any response codes generated by the load balancer.

Graph titled **HTTP 502s** is showing the `HTTPCode_ELB_502_Count` metric. Which is the number of HTTP 502 error codes that **originate from the load balancer**.

So the issue is with the load balancer itself. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-502-issues) for possible causes.

Comment: you are spot on, there was no webserver installed on my machine, so your theory seems plausible